# Compare Database schema to same in SVN repository

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, svn

I would like to compare or monitor a sql file in the Database of SQL Server to the branch/trunk code in SVN where it was located physically.To illustrate if a user has updated a table in a sqlserver Database manually, i wanna compare this database to actual sql file in SVN and find out the changes and make both in Sync or just report the new changes. I could not get a design idea, how to proceed and what are the public APIs available to this so that they can be used in Java.

As a workaround and in my research i found the following tools [red gate](http://www.red-gate.com) .[ApexSQL](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx)
I don't know if this is possible to implement such type of tool on our own(Time is not a constraint). Please add some suggestions, the basic intention of this is to keep track of and report new database changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to detect difference in schema-not the data.

In that case consider using [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/command_line). You can compare databases directly, or you extract schemas from multiple databases and compare the XML yourself.